# How can I change the GUI of JavaFX outside start()?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am crazy about the feature of JavaFX, in Swing, I could do,

```
@Override
    public void onPluginRegistered(final GamePlugin plugin) {
        JRadioButtonMenuItem gameMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(plugin.getGameName());
        gameMenuItem.setSelected(false);
        gameMenuItem.addActionListener(event -> {
            if (core.getPlayers().isEmpty()) {
                // Can't start a game with no players.
                showErrorDialog(frame, ERROR_NO_PLAYERS_TITLE, ERROR_NO_PLAYERS_MSG);
                gameGroup.clearSelection();
            } else {
                core.startNewGame(plugin);
            }
        });
        gameGroup.add(gameMenuItem);
        newGameMenu.add(gameMenuItem);
    }
```

if I want to add a radio item whenever a plugin has registered.
However in JavaFX, it seems, you can't declare any global item of JavaFX, because once the start() is called, it starts a new constructor and everything you've done before is nothing (there is no variable share to me).

Here is my Javafx code.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("./Buttons.css");

        Region spacer = new Region();
        spacer.setMinWidth(10);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tabData = new Tab("Get your data");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabData);
        Tab tabDisplay = new Tab("Visualize your data");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabDisplay);

        pluginGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov,
                Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
                    if (pluginGroup.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                        RadioButton chk = (RadioButton) new_toggle.getToggleGroup().getSelectedToggle();
                        chk.getText();
                    }
                }

        });

        root.setCenter(tabPane);

        FlowPane inputPanel = new FlowPane();
        TextField source = new TextField ();
        Button confirmButton = new Button("Get Your Resource!");
        confirmButton.getStyleClass().add("GREEN");
        inputPanel.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Input your source:"),
                spacer, source, confirmButton);
        root.setBottom(inputPanel);

        RadioButton defaultBtn = new RadioButton("No data plugin are registered");
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Select your data source"), spacer);
        if (radioButtonBox != null) {
            pane.getChildren().add(radioButtonBox);
        }
        tabData.setContent(pane);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPluginRegistered(DataPlugin plugin) {
        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(plugin.getName());
        button.setToggleGroup(pluginGroup);
        radioButtonBox.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    public void caller(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

I want to initialize the javafx program from,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DataFramework core = new ConcreteDataFramework();
    GuiFramework gui = new GuiFramework(core);
    core.addGuiListener(gui);

    gui.caller(args);

    core.registerPlugin(new CsvData());
}
```

It is weird that I can't add any radio button to the existing radioButtonBox every time I call `onPluginRegistered(DataPlugin plugin)` (The new radiobutton does not show up)

Comment: Can you post JavaFX code that is problematic

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Of course you can add javafx elements at runtime. O.o

Comment: I am sorry, the post has been updated.

Comment: Can't you just move the code from your `main` method to the `start` method. You should think of the `start` method as the replacement for `main` in a JavaFX application. (I.e. the application starts with `start()`.) It's not really clear (to me, anyway) where `onPluginRegistered` is called from.

Comment: If I move the code to `start()`, how can I pass variable `framework` to the application?

Comment: Create it in the `start()` method, instead of passing it. Not sure what you are missing here. `start()` is the place where execution starts. Forget `main` exists (a JavaFX application might not have a `main` method, and even if it does it might not be executed). I have no idea what `DataFramework` and `GuiFramework` are, so it's quite difficult to answer the question. Is `GuiFramework` your `Application` subclass? What is `onPluginRegistered` and what is it overriding? You are leaving way too much for us to guess here.\

Comment: You could use ```getParameters()```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the `start()` method as the replacement for the `main` method. If your application needs access to some kind of service or model, create it in the `start()` (or `init()`) method. I would actually recommend making the `Application` subclass (which is inherently not reusable) as minimal as possible - it should just do the startup work - and factoring the remaining GUI code into a separate class. (If you use FXML, the FXML file can define the UI, and the `Application` subclass is then already pretty minimal: it just loads and displays the FXML.)

You haven't really provided enough context to make it clear what's going on here, but I'm guessing `GuiFramework` is the `Application` subclass you've shown part of, and `DataFramework` is an interface of some kind. I also assume `GuiFramework` is implementing some interface that defines the `onPluginRegistered` method.

So I would do:

```
public class GuiFramework implements PluginAware {

    private final BorderPane root ;

    private final DataFramework dataFramework ;

    public GuiFramework(DataFramework dataFramework) {
        this.dataframework = dataFramework ;
        this.root = new BorderPane();

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tabData = new Tab("Get your data");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabData);

        // etc etc (remaining code from your start() method)

    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return root ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPluginRegistered(DataPlugin plugin) {
        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(plugin.getName());
        button.setToggleGroup(pluginGroup);
        radioButtonBox.getChildren().add(button);
    }

}
```

and define a `Main` class for starting the application:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        DataFramework core = new ConcreteDataFramework();
        GuiFramework gui = new GuiFramework(core);
        core.addGuiListener(gui);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gui.getView(), 500, 500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("./Buttons.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        core.registerPlugin(new CsvData());
    }

    // for environments not supporting JavaFX launch automatically:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```